# DataGridView cells

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

My DataGridView has Calendar, CheckBox, TextField columns. But the problem comes in when a user clicks to edit the DataGridView. The user has to Double and Triple click the specified cell in order to access Calendar and CheckBox columns in order to edit. I want to know how to reduce the amount of clicks to one click on the cell should allow the user to edit the cell.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want to do is to set:

`[your_Datagridview].EditMode=DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter`